# Java Webstart deny closing

Tags: java, applet, oracleforms

i am desperatly trying to deny the applet closing, that did get started with the java webstart. I have tried to find the parent `JFrame` and adding a `WindowListener` to it and to override the `stop` method inside the `Applet`.
The `Main` class in this case is a class provided by Oracle for `Oracle Forms`.
It´s a class that does inherit from `Applet`.

What is happening right now is that i am getting a message `KILLING PROCESS`, but the applet immidiatly starts to close, despite the `JOptionPane` call, which theoreticly should let the closing wait until i do close the message.

Additionally i tried to set the `JFrame#setDefaultCloseOperation` to `JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`, but it´s allways getting set to `JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE`.

So my question, what´s the way for the java webstart to properly listen to the close event of the main `Frame` and deny it from closing when pressing the Close button.

Code for the `Applet`

```
public class ResizableWSApplet extends Main {
    private JFrame root = null;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();
        Component parent;
        parent = this;
          // Find the parent JFrame 
        while(parent.getParent()!=null) parent = parent.getParent();
        if (parent instanceof JFrame) {
            root = (JFrame) parent;
        }
          // Remove WindowListener as a test
        for(WindowListener l : root.getWindowListeners())
            root.removeWindowListener(l);
    }

    protected Frame getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("KILLING PROCESS");  
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(root, "TEST");
        //super.windowClosing(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        System.out.println("TEST1");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "TEST");
        super.stop();
    }
}
```

last few lines of the trace file:

```
KILLING PROCESS
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: applet.ResizableWSApplet$OsCheck$OSType: try again ..
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: oracle.ewt.lwAWT.lwText.AutoScroller: try again ..
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: oracle.forms.ui.DropDownEvent: try again ..
Plugin2Manager calling stopFailed() because of exception during AppContext.dispose()
Plugin2Manager calling stopFailed() because of displayable window java.awt.Frame[frame1,0,0,132x38,invalid,hidden,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=,resizable,normal]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Oracle Forms 12c. It's fixed by interim patch 23123655, which must be applied on top of 12.2.1.1 (patchset 1). It will also be included in 12.2.1.2, whenever it's available. No fix exists for the original 12.2.1.0 release.